# Discord.py commands cooldown on specific if statement

Tags: python, discord.py

Im still figuring out on how to make a command cooldown if some statement is met. I will use this code as an example.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    role1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Test Role')
    if role1 in ctx.message.author.roles:
        em1 = discord.Embed(title = 'Test Title', description = f'You are in {role1.mention}, wait for 5 minutes before sending this command again.',color = ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em1)
    else:
        em2 = discord.Embed(title = 'Test Title', description = f'You are not in {role1.mention}.',color = ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em2)
```

I want the cooldown only apply for the "If role1 in ctx.author.message.roles:" one and not for the "else:". When im using "@commands.cooldown", its apply for the whole statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else`, you could reset the cooldown using `test.reset_cooldown(ctx)`.
But there would still be cooldown if you first executed that what's after `if role1 in ctx.message.author.roles:`, so you need a handler for that, which also executes the second part of the code:

```py
@test.error
async def test_handler(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        if role1 in ctx.message.author.roles:
             #here you could write a message to discord saying "This command is currently on cooldown" or something similar.
        else:
            em2 = discord.Embed(title = 'Test Title', description = f'You are not in {role1.mention}.',color = ctx.author.color)
            await ctx.send(embed = em2)
    else:
        print(error)
```

So your final code would be:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user) #whatever you want to use here
async def test(ctx):
    role1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Test Role')
    if role1 in ctx.message.author.roles:
        em1 = discord.Embed(title = 'Test Title', description = f'You are in {role1.mention}, wait for 5 minutes before sending this command again.',color = ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em1)
    else:
        test.reset_cooldown(ctx)
        em2 = discord.Embed(title = 'Test Title', description = f'You are not in {role1.mention}.',color = ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em2)


@test.error
async def test_handler(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        if role1 in ctx.message.author.roles:
             #here you could write a message to discord saying "This command is currently on cooldown" or something similar.
        else:
            em2 = discord.Embed(title = 'Test Title', description = f'You are not in {role1.mention}.',color = ctx.author.color)
            await ctx.send(embed = em2)
    else:
        print(error)
```

Comment: Or instead of all that you can use the has_role decorator

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński While that is true and would be cleaner in this case, the question explicitly asks how to use checks in if-statements to trigger the cooldown, so this is a better *answer* than using the decorator imo.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. It’s a note for OP if he wants to improve his code.